# Plotting Split Violin Plots

Tags: python, ipython, seaborn, violin-plot

I'm using Seaborn in Python to make violin plots.  I have two columns, one with data and the other categorical (a or b).  I want to make a split violin plot - one half of it would show the density for the whole data set and the other would show the density for samples belonging to category a.  Is this possible?

Comment: There's not an argument in the function that will do this but it's easy to accomplish by making a new dataset with all of the observations and then the observations from the group you care about duplicated (with a new column identifying which is which).